# Cannot import library that's in the same folder as other working libraries

Tags: python, module, libraries

Very new at python and coding in general, my apologies if I'm not giving relevant information.
I'm running into a problem with importing libraries, to be specific, nltk and textblob. In the same python file I also have spacy and pandas loaded [see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/duNc6.png) which are working absolutely fine and are imported correctly. When I run the file I get this error message:

> Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError No module named 'nltk'
> File "/Users/myname/Documents/Python/sentiment analysis.py", line 3,
> in 
> import nltk ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nltk'

When checking file locations etc, it appears that all the libraries including the not working one are all in the same path

If it's relevant, I'm using VScode.

pip's have been installed, I've also uninstalled and reinstalled both libraries but the problem remains

Comment: you need to `pip install nltk`. Here are the instructions:  https://pypi.org/project/nltk/

Comment: If you installed nltk, maybe you are using another virtual environment to run your python script than where you installed nltk.